# Android : How to get simcard mobile number

Tags: android

I want to get Sim Card Mobile number of the device which use my App. I have number of answer but there not perfect code. Please Give me supporting link or code to use in my android app.

Comment: Is the movile have more than one sim?

Comment: TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager) this
       .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
     String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();

Comment: @Narkha Yes we have dual sim

Answer (score 0):

```
TelephonyManager telemamanger = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String getSimNumber = telemamanger.getLine1Number();
```

You will also need to add this permission in `AndroidManifeast.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

The documentation for [TelephonyManager.getLine1Number()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getLine1Number%28%29) says this method will return null if the number is "unavailable", but it does not say when the number might be unavailable.

Comment: These may fail several times..Do u have any other altrenative

Comment: As I know there are no alternatives. Not all simcards allows to read MSISDN from them and in this case android api don't know it.

Comment: Its not working, i haven't get any mobile number.

Answer (score 0):

Earlier I was trying to achieve this. It mostly depend on the simcard provider. Like Airtel(India) does not allow mobile number to be identifed through code but if you try Aircel it do provide phone number.

Comment: No its not working in Aircel also.